# How to insert (La)TeX symbol

Tags: logos

I saw this symbol recently used in the TeXworks user manual, I'd like to know how to insert it. I found it in the manual on GitHub ([link](https://github.com/TeXworks/manual/releases/download/2020-03-29/TeXworks-manual-en.pdf)), it was on page 7 at the bottom. I have never seen it before and was wondering if there is a command for it.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are the commands like `\TeX` and `\LaTeX`

Comment: do you mean (La)TeX (there is one on page 8 but I didn't see one onpage 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hologo}

\begin{document}

Most people use \verb|(La)\TeX| producing:
(La)\TeX.

\textsf{hologo} provides \verb|\hologo{LaTeXTeX}| producing:
\hologo{LaTeXTeX}.

\end{document}
```